# I get an error from sql .delete after updating sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, vb6, sql-delete, rdo

We support a V6 program. The code does a query, gets the result set, and performs a .delete on the result, no problem. We updated to SQL server 2005, and the .delete suddenly fails with the vague "The statement has been terminated" error.

I rewrite the code to do a Delete query instead of a .delete on the rdo resultset as a workaround - this works. But I know there are several more instances waiting for me. Any ideas?

Comment: *"We updated to SQL server 2005"* "updated"? SQL Server 2005 went out of support years ago already, as have 2008 *and* 2012.

Comment: Since he mentions vb6, i don't think using up-to-date SQL Server is the biggest priority here

Comment: You're not supposed to be using either vb6, RDO (ADO is better) nor SQL Server 2005. Probably something changed between versions regarding to cursors. Maybe if you post the code that handles the delete, it would be easier to understand

Comment: @Larnu not to mention that VB6 has been unsupported since 2008. It may be painful but the OP is going to have to commit to a rewrite into a modern language soon. I suspect it won't be much longer before the OS won't even run some of these things.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.